# Is there a way to call Scatter Gather on Subflows and maintain the order of execution?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am calling 2 subflows in parallel by calling scattergather and  aggregating the responses from 2 subflows.

Status is one of the element (tag) being returned by both the subflows.

i.e one of the subflow returns below status

```
 <Status>
    <StatusCode>-1000</StatusCode>
    <Severity>Error</Severity>
    <StatusDesc>ERROR</StatusDesc>
</Status>
```

and other Subflow returns

```
    <Status>
        <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
        <Severity>Info</Severity>
        <StatusDesc>INFO</StatusDesc>
    </Status>
```

When I write Junits for the same, the Junit passes at times and fails at times as the order of Status tag varies. So is there anyway to make sure the response of 1 subflow is considered 1st and  response of other subflow is considered later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all depends on the `MessageChannel` configuration you have for those scatter-gather sub-flows. If you don't shift the work into other threads until you send a reply from sub-flow back to the scatter-gather for an aggregator to do its work, then everything should be gathered in the proper order.

Another trick is to configure a gatherer part to reorder messages when you build a result from a group. Probably this is the best approach for your unit testing: I don't think you would be happy with a blocking solution for production.